# Regexing a list of characters in sed

Tags: sed

I have a list of chars:

```
11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false -- "-"
```

If I want to take all until the false (including) with `grep` I use:

```
grep -o '[0-9].* [a-z]* '
```

What is the analog in `sed`?

Comment: You could use `sed 's/\([0-9].* [a-z]*\) .*/\1/'` or `sed 's/ -- .*//'`, but what's transferable about this? What's the point of it? You don't need `-P` for that `grep` BTW...

Comment: I don't get your `grep` command. It does not work if some string is following after *false*.  `[0-9].*` doesn't make sense. You may want `[0-9]*`.

Comment: @RoVo, I think the regexp is correct if the desired captured part is `11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false `, but it is too broad.

Comment: But then `[0-9]` is not necessary. Just `.*` would be fine.

Comment: Or maybe `^.* ` if really this is the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of this regular expression in `sed` is identical. For example if you want to replace the string(s) that matches to this regular expression, you can use the substitute command in the following way (`s/<old>/<new>/`):

```bsh
$ echo '11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false -- "-"' | sed 's/[0-9].* [a-z]* /_THE_NEW_STRING_/'
_THE_NEW_STRING_-- "-"
```

Of course you can use extended regular expressions `-r`, `--regexp-extended` to make your life easy in some cases:

```bsh
$ echo '11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false -- "-"' | sed -r 's/([0-9].* [a-z]* ).*/\1/'
11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false 

$ echo '11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false -- "-"' | sed -r 's/([0-9].* [a-z]* )(.*)/\2 \1/'
-- "-" 11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false
```

Comment: Not working: `$ echo '11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false 00000 999 xxx test 1-#+X abc -- "-" test' | sed -r 's/([0-9].* [a-z]* ).*/\1/'`
--> 
`11183 11183 1 0 0 0 0 false 00000 999 xxx test 1-#+X abc `

Comment: @RoVo, I'm agree with your worry about the regexp, but IMO the question is not about that.

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` command will return anything (`.*`) from the beginning of the line (`^`), until and including the first occurence of `false` excluding the rest (`.*$`).

```
sed -r 's/^(.*\<false\>).*$/\1/'
```

Comment: why the empty capture group?

Comment: I try matching `false`, but not `notfalse` or `falsetto`. It could be `( false )` , but I don't want to echo the last space.

Comment: Ah :) GNU `sed` supports word boundaries so you can use `\<false\>` (works if before is start of line or after is end of line). But OP's example doesn't require it. I think the question is pointless because there's no way to tell what's unique or transferable about their requirement

Comment: that's why I sometimes still answer pointless questions ;-) ... practice and learn new stuff. thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how this scenario could be implemented if `false` is not `false`,  but it is the first occurrence of an alphabet string. RoVo, @Zanna, any ideas?

Comment: @pa4080 show your input and desired output please ;)

Comment: @Zanna, for example if in the place of `false` we have different values - false, true, mouse, etc., but we don't know them. If the possible values are only `false` or `true` we could extend RoVo's command in this way: `sed -r 's/^(.*\<false\>|.*\<true\>).*$/\1/'`, but when we just expect a world and don't know what it could be - is there a way to tell `sed` this is the first match of `[a-z]*` string? Here is an example: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rwTkWTFgJq/

Comment: @pa4080 maybe you want negation? Like `sed -r 's/([^[a-z]]* [a-z]*) .*/\1/'` Sorry I can't answer in the abstract. (Don't agree that `sed` isn't the right tool - any relatively simple text processing can be done with `sed`)